# What is proper posting of javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are these two below the same?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('.fancybox').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 700,
        maxHeight   : 550,
        minHeight   : 500,
        closeBtn:true
    });
    $j('a.fancybox').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 700,
        maxHeight   : 550,
        minHeight   : 500,
        closeBtn:true
    });
    $j('#homeslider iframe').each(function() {
        var url = $j(this).attr("src")
        $j(this).attr("src",url+"&amp;wmode=Opaque")
    });
});
</script>
<script>
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function(){
    // jQuery UI Dialog  
    $j('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit Form": function() {
                document.testconfirmJQ.submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

and this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('.fancybox').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 700,
        maxHeight   : 550,
        minHeight   : 500,
        closeBtn:true
    });
    $j('a.fancybox').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 700,
        maxHeight   : 550,
        minHeight   : 500,
        closeBtn:true
    });
    $j('#homeslider iframe').each(function() {
        var url = $j(this).attr("src")
        $j(this).attr("src",url+"&amp;wmode=Opaque")
    });
});
$j(function(){
    // jQuery UI Dialog  
    $j('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit Form": function() {
                document.testconfirmJQ.submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

I removed the close script and start new one to connect these two.  I also removed the redundant noConflict.  Why do I get different behavior with these two different uses in my header?

Comment: can you provide a test case which shows that these behave differently? They shouldn't.

Comment: How about *describing* the behavior.

Comment: makes no sense... something else must have changed also, could rearrange your code multiple ways and still will always provide same behavior

Comment: My header file has each script posted as the first window.  The first question asks "If these are the same?".  If so, can I remove the redundant `</script><script>` as well as the `$j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: I edited the original and changed the code to the actual code from my header that breaks when I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not described what is changing. But looking at it, I'm guessing your second `script` never worked to begin with.

They're the same, but toward the end if your second `script`, you have a misplaced `return false`. This is a syntax error which will have an impact on the entire `script` when they're joined together.

```
$j(function(){
    // jQuery UI Dialog  
    $j('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Submit Form": function() {
                document.testconfirmJQ.submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
                $j(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
        return false;  // INVALID SYNTAX
    });
});
```

Please keep your browser's developer console open during development. This would have told you about the syntax error, and should be the first place you go to diagnose problems.

When you do post a question that you can't figure out, please post a complete example right from the start.

Also, when you post a question, don't use vague terms like "behaves differently" or "doesn't work". Describe in detail what you observe.

Comment: Thanks.  Should I take that `return false` out and leave the rest as is?